# partial formatting in excel cell using xml spreadsheet in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, xml, excel

I  want to bold particular word of a particular cell. I have successfully exported the  the excel sheet from VF page and applied styles on individual cells. Now I want to bold a specific word from controller.

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="someStyleId">
     <Data ss:Type="String">
          <apex:outputText value="In this statement i want **california** to be bold." escape="false"   />  
     </Data>
</Cell>
```

Output

In this statement i want **california** to be bold.
There can be more data but i want only few words to be bold.

Comment: Yeah.. i want just a part of a cell to be bold. As given in example code @adrian

Comment: Can you at least clarify rules around what should be bold? Always the word `california`? State names? The sixth word? Words with ten characters?

Comment: no. i want to bold a particular word irrespective of its position and length.

Comment: To be more specific , In a cell I have first line as project title and then in second line I have details about that project. I want only project title(first line) to be bold in that cell.

Comment: I am stuck in this since last 2 days. Any help would be greatfull.

Comment: Can you share the approach? Is this world already in bold in the excel?

Comment: We can apply style(bold,italic or any other style) to whole cell using ss:StyleId. But i want only one or few words bold in excel sheet cell. Right now that word is not coming in bold in excel sheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An excel cell row which have partial worlds in bold should look like this:

```
    <Cell>
       <Data ss:Type="String">
         <Font html:Color="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">ABC</Font>
         <B xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
          <Font html:Color="#000000">**This is bold**</Font>
         </B>
         <Font html:Color="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">RTT</Font>
       </Data>
    </Cell>
```

Look at the styles applied for "This is bold" string.

So, simply pass on the html in `<Data/>` tag into the `<outputText/>`. It will work.

Comment: Perfect. Thanx Ashwani

Answer (score -1):

`<apex:outputText>` tag have a attribute called `escape` takes boolean value which you have already used without knowing its use.

> A Boolean value that specifies whether sensitive HTML and XML
>   characters should be escaped in the HTML output generated by this
>   component. If you don’t specify escape="false", the character escape
>   sequence displays as written. Be aware that setting this value to
>   "false" may be a security risk because it allows arbitrary content,
>   including JavaScript, that could be used in a malicious manner.

So you have to provide the html tags for bold inside the body of the outputText tag with escape="false" and it will display it for you.

```
<apex:outputText value="In this statement i want <br>california</br> to be bold." escape="false"   />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does this work in Excel?

Comment: Well i have tried using the below statement but bold text was not reflecting in excel sheet generated. 
**<apex:outputText value="In this statement i want <b>california</b> to be bold." escape="false"   /> **

Do i have to use <br> for bold?

Comment: @max, `<br>` is for line break right? I am also trying from last 2 hrs but could not get it working. I will post if I get some solution. Thanks!

Comment: yeah <br> is for line break.